# Create a post body from a url in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, url

suppose i have a url with parameters like this:

```
allowedCardTypes=master%2Cvisa&callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fstage.masterpassteststore.com%2Fteststorefront%2F%3Fsdk%3Djava%23%2Fcallback%2Fcheckout%3Freload%3Dtrue&merchantCheckoutId=f5d29dd838bd4e97a280a9e2a00d9f63
```

I want to create and object like this:

```
{
  allowedCardTypes: master%2Cvisa,
  callbackUrl: https%3A%2F%2Fstage.masterpassteststore.com%2Fteststorefront%2F%3Fsdk%3Djava%23%2Fcallback%2Fcheckout%3Freload%3Dtrue

}
```

Any ideas? Does js have a function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

This solution will actually create better strings for you (quotes and unescaped)

```js
let parms = {"allowedCardTypes":"","callbackUrl":""}
const searchParams = "allowedCardTypes=master%2Cvisa&callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fstage.masterpassteststore.com%2Fteststorefront%2F%3Fsdk%3Djava%23%2Fcallback%2Fcheckout%3Freload%3Dtrue&merchantCheckoutId=f5d29dd838bd4e97a280a9e2a00d9f63"
const url = new URL("http://test.com?"+searchParams);
for (let parm in parms) {
  parms[parm] = url.searchParams.get(parm);
}
console.log(parms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your url is a string, you can set it as a variable, perform some basic string manipulation on it, and then save it as key value pairs in an object:

```js
var url = "allowedCardTypes=master%2Cvisa&callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fstage.masterpassteststore.com%2Fteststorefront%2F%3Fsdk%3Djava%23%2Fcallback%2Fcheckout%3Freload%3Dtrue&merchantCheckoutId=f5d29dd838bd4e97a280a9e2a00d9f63"

var array = url.split("&callbackUrl=")
//console.log('array is: ', array)

var allowedCarTypesValue = array[0].split("allowedCardTypes=")
//console.log('allowedCarTypesValue: ', allowedCarTypesValue)

var obj = {
  allowedCardTypes: allowedCarTypesValue[1],
  callbackUrl: array[1]
};

console.log('obj is: ', obj)
```